# Multiprocessing through file tree not outputting expected output

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Multiprocessing through a directory tree is not working as expected. I'm trying to add all `iso` files to a single `set()` and output just that set. I'm aware that I'm telling python to return `None` but I don't know how else I can do this without returning `None`. How can I output a singular set from multiprocessing?

```
import itertools
import multiprocessing


def worker(filename):
    data_set = set()
    if ".iso" in filename:
        data_set.add(filename)
    return data_set if len(data_set) != 0 else None


def search_for_iso(dirname=None, verbose=False, default_path="/"):
    iso_found = set()
    if dirname is None:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=48)
        walker = os.walk(default_path)
        file_data_gen = itertools.chain.from_iterable((
            os.path.join(root, f) for f in files) for root, sub, files in walker)
        results = pool.map(worker, file_data_gen)
        return results
```

As of now it will output the following: `set(['/test.iso', None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, .....]) # whole lot of None's`

Expected output: `set(['/test.iso'])`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution for this by running through the results of the processing and checking if the file ends with `.iso`:

```
def worker(filename):
    if filename.endswith(".iso"):
        return filename


def search_for_iso(dirname=None, verbose=False, default_path="/"):
    retval = set()
    if dirname is None:
        pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=48)
        walker = os.walk(default_path)
        file_data_gen = itertools.chain.from_iterable((
            os.path.join(root, f) for f in files) for root, sub, files in walker)
        results = pool.map(worker, file_data_gen)
        for data in results:
            if data is not None:
                retval.add(data)
        return retval
```

This seems to work just fine and doesn't seem to slow down the process at all

Answer (score 0):

First of all you won't get any extra performance using multiple processes, because you will still have to wait for the file system which is much much slower than the cpu.

As for your current code, just return the set , even if it's empty

```
def worker(filename):
    data_set = set()
    if ".iso" in filename:
        data_set.add(filename)
    return data_set
```